# Errors on "npm install -g n"

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to install node version controller when i ran into this..

[image: errors on console]

this is my PC configuration

[image: My Laptop Configuration]

Thanks for help in advance..

Comment: While not explicitly stated on the project site (https://github.com/visionmedia/n) the error message seems pretty clear. It doesn't seem to support Windows

Comment: Thanks, But does this mean i cant even try koa using windows..

Comment: I have never run Node.js on Windows, and not tried Koa at all. But Koa does not seem to explicitly depend on n, just a certain version of Node. If you can install that version directly I see no reason why you wouldn't be able to run Koa. But note that this is just guesswork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i could read from the comments, you are trying to install n because you wanna use `KoA`

But Koa itself has nothing to do with `n`. `n` is basically just a Support-Application which makes it easy for you to install and switch between whatever Node-Version you want by a single CLI-Command. Since you need Node > 0.11.x for KoA, they say on their page to install `n` so you can, after trying KoA, switch easily back to a stable Node-Version.

Im afraid you have no other option than manually downloading the latest Node-Unstable Version from their page and install it "by hand".

Comment: how would i switch it to my stable version of node then?
That's a big question too...
This would make it even more hectic..
I think i should report this issue

Comment: Well, you can always install two or more instances of node on your machine - also on windows...

Comment: Thanks Charminbear... I installed Ubuntu... so i may not have to deal with further inconvenience...